# How to stretch the div to all the height of the page?

Tags: html, css

I ran into an issue while using CSS.
I have two divs (Sidebar "lbar" and Content "rfeed") These two divs are supposed to be stretched to the very bottom of the page. Well, they are now only to the point where the text ends as you can see in the screenshot. I tried to fix it, but i did not find anyone to have the same issue as i do. I think it's because of the flex display, but i need to use it.[image: How the page looks like]

This is my code

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .feed {
        display: flex;
      }
      .lbar {
        flex: 20%;
        background-color: #333333;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
        min-height: 100%;
        float: left;
      }
      .rfeed {
        flex: 80%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        color: white;
      }
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      .name {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .rank {
        background-color: #6321ff;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      button {
        background-color: #0063db;
        border: 5px #0073e6 solid;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 19px;
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #0063db 50%, #0073e6 50%) right;
        background-size: 200%;
        transition: .5s ease-out;
      }
      button:hover {
        background-position: left;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      button:active {
        transform: translateY(5px);
      }
      .topmenu {
        background-color: #333333;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .menuitem {
        margin: 20px;
      }
      .menuitem:hover {
        text-decoration: overline;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .menuactive {
        background-color: #0063db;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
      table, th, td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
        border-top: 1px solid #333333;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      th {
        text-align: left;
      }
      td {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panel - Podpora │ Minex</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="feed">
      <div class="lbar">
        <img src="https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/cyan/190.png">
        <p class="name">Content</p>
        <p class="rank">Content</p>
        <button type="button" name="logout" style="margin-top: 90px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="changepass" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="updateskin" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin: 0px; color: #191919;">
      <div class="rfeed">
        <div class="topmenu">
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="../index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem" style="background-color: #0063db; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 5px #0073e6 solid;"><a href="index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="content/index.html">Content</a></b>
        </div>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th>
            </tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>              
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `min-height` for `.lbar` to `calc(100vh - 30px)`. We subtract `30px` to account for the extra padding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.feed {
  display: flex;
}

.lbar {
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  float: left;
}

.rfeed {
  flex: 80%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.name {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.rank {
  background-color: #6321ff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: #0063db;
  border: 5px #0073e6 solid;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #0063db 50%, #0073e6 50%) right;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  background-position: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.topmenu {
  background-color: #333333;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuitem {
  margin: 20px;
}

.menuitem:hover {
  text-decoration: overline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuactive {
  background-color: #0063db;
}

table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Panel - Podpora │ Minex</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="feed">
      <div class="lbar">
        <img src="https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/cyan/190.png">
        <p class="name">Content</p>
        <p class="rank">Content</p>
        <button type="button" name="logout" style="margin-top: 90px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="changepass" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="updateskin" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin: 0px; color: #191919;">
      <div class="rfeed">
        <div class="topmenu">
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="../index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem" style="background-color: #0063db; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 5px #0073e6 solid;"><a href="index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="content/index.html">Content</a></b>
        </div>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Content</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `.content` and `.feed` to have a `height: 100%`, I just included them with `html` and `body`:

```
html, body, .content, .feed {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And also remove the `min-height` from `.lbar`. The final code should look like this:

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
      html, body, .content, .feed {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .feed {
        display: flex;
      }
      .lbar {
        flex: 20%;
        background-color: #333333;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
        float: left;
      }
      .rfeed {
        flex: 80%;
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        color: white;
      }
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      .name {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .rank {
        background-color: #6321ff;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      button {
        background-color: #0063db;
        border: 5px #0073e6 solid;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 19px;
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #0063db 50%, #0073e6 50%) right;
        background-size: 200%;
        transition: .5s ease-out;
      }
      button:hover {
        background-position: left;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      button:active {
        transform: translateY(5px);
      }
      .topmenu {
        background-color: #333333;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .menuitem {
        margin: 20px;
      }
      .menuitem:hover {
        text-decoration: overline;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .menuactive {
        background-color: #0063db;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
      table, th, td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
        border-top: 1px solid #333333;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      th {
        text-align: left;
      }
      td {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panel - Podpora │ Minex</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="feed">
      <div class="lbar">
        <img src="https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/cyan/190.png">
        <p class="name">Content</p>
        <p class="rank">Content</p>
        <button type="button" name="logout" style="margin-top: 90px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="changepass" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
        <button type="button" name="updateskin" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content</button>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin: 0px; color: #191919;">
      <div class="rfeed">
        <div class="topmenu">
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="../index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem" style="background-color: #0063db; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border: 5px #0073e6 solid;"><a href="index.html">Content</a></b>
          <b class="menuitem"><a href="content/index.html">Content</a></b>
        </div>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th>
            </tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td><td>Content</td> <td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>              
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```